convert to normal string
I have python file like this
_ = lambda __ : _ = lambda __ : __import__('zlib').decompress(__import__('base64').b64decode(__[::-1]));exec((_)(b'=4BAC7FA//++8/vllGe9E9ENSg8u'))


How to convert to normal string file ?!!

Do you know for certain what will execute when run?

The only reason anyone would have written code like this is to hide some malicious activity.  The only safe thing to do with code like this is to delete it.

If you reverse, decode, and uncompress this, you get another exec with a long string.  If you reverse, decode, and uncompress THAT, you get yet another exec with a long string.  After you do that 7 or 8 times, you get Python code that imports inc_noesis and registers something about "diablo immortal".

Correction -- it's not 7 or 8 times, it's 49 times.  Stupid.  Anyone who can decode this once can decode it in a loop.

It's some kind of game texture skin thing.  https://github.com/search?q=inc_noesis.py+&type=code , https://github.com/Hengle/noesis_py etc

@TimRoberts Very good, but why do you both vote-to-close and answer? Answering means you think the question should be answered, closing means the opposite.

Yes, I thought about that.  I don't think the question has long-term value, but there's no good way to provide a code response except in an answer.  I abused the system, if you will.

@TimRoberts - The geek portion of my brain appreciates your abuse of the system.  Going to dig a bit deeper into this ‘unraveling’ later.

If you really want to see what's in this, here's code to do it.  My code this never uses exec, so it is safe.  The resulting Python file has had all of the variable names shrouded.
import base64
import zlib

s = b'=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'

t = base64.b64decode(s[::-1])
u = zlib.decompress(t)
cnt = 0
while u[0] != ord('f'):
    cnt = cnt + 1
    i = u.find(b"'")
    j = u.rfind(b"'")
    u = u[i:j][::-1]
    v = base64.b64decode(u)
    u = zlib.decompress(v)

print(u.decode())
print(cnt)


why all variable names get like
for _OOOO00O0OO0OOO000 in range (OOOO0O00O0OO0O00O ):#line:86
_O00OO0OOO0000O0O0 =_OOOOO0OOOOO000000 .tell ()#line:87
_OOOOO0OOOOO000000 .seek (O0OO00O000O000OOO [0 ],1 )#line:88
_O0OOOOOOOOOOO000O .append (NoeVec3 .fromBytes (_OOOOO0OOOOO000000 .read (12 )))#line:89
_OOOOO0OOOOO000000 .seek (_O00OO0OOO0000O0O0 +OO000000OO000O0OO )

Surely you can figure this out.  This code has been run through a "shrouding" program that is trying to hide the original purpose of the code.  Part of that involves changing all of the variable names to nonsense names.  It doesn't change the meaning.  You can use an editor to change them to "x" and "y" or whatever.
